# Echo Each Item From Array With Foreach Function

Tags: php, json

I'm not really experienced in PHP JSON queries, I'm curious if someone could help me with it.

I'm trying to make a foreach call for every color in the JSON array (seen below).

something like this

```
foreach($json->data->colors as $color){
  echo '<option value="'.$color.'">'.$color.'</option>';
}
```

JSON File

```
{
    "data": {
        "colors": [
            "Red",
            "Blue",
            "Green",
            "Yellow",
            "Pink"
        ],
        "Shapes": [
            "Square",
            "Rectangle",
            "Circle",
            "Triangle"
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: How are you turning your JSON file into `$json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to parse the JSON data, use `json_decode()` on your JSON string. And then loop through the parsed JSON variable like you're doing.

**Complete code:**

```
<?php

$jsonString = '{
    "data": {
        "colors": [
            "Red",
            "Blue",
            "Green",
            "Yellow",
            "Pink"
        ],
        "Shapes": [
            "Square",
            "Rectangle",
            "Circle",
            "Triangle"
        ]
    }
}';

$json = json_decode($jsonString);

echo '<select type="select" name="select">';
foreach($json->data->colors as $color){
  echo '<option value="'.$color.'">'.$color.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I wasn't using the `json_decode` function.

I hate to be a bother but I have one last question. Is it possible to define a JSON file in one page and use it on another?

I've defined the `file_get_contents("file.json")` in `config.php` but when I go to the index page in another directory with `require('config.php')`, it throws and error saying the file doesnt exists. 

I'm assuming its trying to locate the JSON in the same directory as the index page.

Comment: Yes, you can. Make sure to provide the absolute or relative path of the config.php file.